# Distributed Tensorflow not working with simple example

Tags: python, tensorflow, distributed-computing, distributed

I'm following an example [here](https://github.com/ischlag/distributed-tensorflow-example/blob/master/example.py) to learn distributed TF on MNIST. I changed the cluster config to:

```
parameter_servers = ["1.2.3.4:2222"]
workers = [ "1.2.3.4:2222", "5.6.7.8:2222"]
```

`1.2.3.4` and `5.6.7.8` are just representations of my two nodes. They are not the real IP address. The whole script is named `example.py`

On `1.2.3.4`, I ran: `python example.py --job_name=ps --task_index=0`
.Then on the same machine, I ran `python example --job_name=worker --task_index=0` in a different terminal. Looks like it's just waiting.

On `5,6,7,8`, I ran `python example.py --job_name=worker --taks_index=1`. After that I immediately get the following error on `5.6.7.8`:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.UnavailableError: {"created":"@1480458325.580095889","description":"EOF","file":"external/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_posix.c","file_line":235,"grpc_status":14}
I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/master_session.cc:845] DeregisterGraph error: Aborted: Graph handle is not found: . Possibly, this worker just restarted.
```

And

```
tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/graph_mgr.cc:55] 'unit.device' Must be non NULL
Aborted (core dumped)
```

on `1.2.3.4`

Is this because I'm running both the parameter server and worker on the same machine? I don't have more than 2 nodes so how do I fix this?

Comment: Here's a self-contained example of running 2 workers on single node, can you see if that works for you? https://gist.github.com/yaroslavvb/1124bb02a9fd4abce3d86caf2f950cb2

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov: It works but I get CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY on a GPU server (with 1 GPU).

Comment: You need to do "export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=" for one of the processes, by default it grabs all GPU memory. With that set, there should be no problem running parameter server and worker on the same machine.

Comment: That fixed it. If you provide that as an answer, i'd accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a day I finally got the fix:

1. Do as Yaroslav suggest for the param server, so that the worker doesn't run out of GPU memory
2. The param server and worker cannot run on the same port (as the original post), so change `workers = [ "1.2.3.4:2222", "5.6.7.8:2222"]` to `workers = [ "1.2.3.4:2223", "5.6.7.8:2222"]`. Note the change in port number.

That's everything that needs to be done.